# How can I find out the link to POST to with Jsoup?

Tags: java, url, authentication, jsoup

I am currently trying to write a program in jsoup to login to mijn.nuon.nl .
when I visit the page with the browser I get redirected to some very long URL that I'm not able to reach with my code.
Could someone help me identify the right url to post to and maybe take a look at my code?
Thank you very much

```
Connection.Response res = Jsoup.connect("https://nuon.nl/service/mijn-nuon").referrer("https://nuon.nl/").userAgent("Mozilla/5.0").timeout(1000 * 100000).followRedirects(true).execute();

Map<String, String> mapLoginPageCookies = res.cookies();

res= Jsoup.connect(redir.toString()).data("email", username, "password", 
password).data("sessionDataKey","9452a647-8c87-41b8-870a-1b48796b106d")
.method(Connection.Method.POST)
.userAgent("Mozilla/5.0")
.timeout(10 * 1000).execute();
```

Answer (score 0):

try this to get final redirected url:

```
res.url().toString();
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I had already tried that though and it does not show the same link as in the browser, I also tried posting to that specific link and it does not work.

Comment: @mike seems like website redirects the page using javascript I don't think Jsoup can handle something like this

Comment: Thanks, but can't i find out from chrome or somewhere else the url? i'm not even sure if the url includes the session therefore if jsoup is not getting redirected, then it is impossible for it to connect.
Is there another better library that can handle this kind of situation then?
I apologize for the amount of questions and thanks so much for taking the time to check it

Comment: @mike try this address to post data to it : https://accountsng.nuon.nl/iamng/nlb2c/login
for other solution I guest selenium would work for this kind of situation, but I didn't use it

Comment: Thanks a lot for looking into the link.
I have ran a GET on the link and downloaded to file and it looks like it's the correct page but now the POST method called on that page i get a URL error status 404.
I don't know if i'm posting worng or if jsoup is having trouble with ssl.
Have you ever had similar problems?

Comment: @mike if there is problem with ssl u can use .validateTLSCertificates(false)